# extract parts of images from a video and save it to a file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video of 2000 x 200 pixels in resolution
I need to grab two parts inside that video (cut into the image, not trimming).

I need to grab a piece of 500 x 200 pixels from coordinates (0,0) and another 500 x 200 pixels from coordinates (1000,0), then merge them side by side into a new 1000 x pixels video file.

[image]

is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Command template is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -filter_complex "[0]crop=500:200:0:0[l];[0]crop=500:200:1000:0[r]; \
                                     [l][r]hstack" final.mov
```

Comment: Very nice @Mulvya ! I am very new to ffmpeg.
This is just perfect.
What a useful tool ffmpeg is ! Can you explain some details though ? - what are those [] tags ?
- and what "hstack" stands for ? thanks a lot

Comment: hstack is a filter which stacks videos (of same height) horizontally. The brackets with a string are pads - read about them at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1